# Treemap (plotly) color intensity according to a variable

Tags: r, plotly, treemap

I made a treemap using the `treemap` package, in which the area of each box is related to the `Valor` variable and the color of each box is related to the `escala` variable, which was created from the `Nota` variable. In red to gray scale, as shown below:

```
library(data.table)
library(tidyverse)
library(treemap)
url <- "https://raw.githack.com/fsbmat-ufv/stackExchange/main/df2.csv"
df <- fread(url)
df$scale <- scale(df$Nota)
treemap(df, index = "MUNICIPIO", vSize = "Valor", vColor = "scale",
        type = "value", palette = "-RdGy", lowerbound.cex.labels = 0.1,
        title = "Treemap Rio de Janeiro",
        overlap.labels=0.05)
```

[image: insert image description here]

I would like to create the same `treemap` with `plotly`, or a very similar one, such that the area of the boxes are related to the variable `Valor` and the color is in intensity related to the variable `Nota` or the variable `escala`. I created the code below but I was not successful. Does anyone have a suggestion?

```
color <- colorRamp(c("red", "gray"))
colorlist <- rgb(color((df$Nota)/max(df$Nota)), max = 255)
df %>%
  plotly::plot_ly(labels = ~ MUNICIPIO,
                  values = ~Valor,
                  parents = ~NA,
                  type = 'treemap',
                  hovertemplate = "City: %{label}<extra></extra>") %>%
  plotly::layout(title = "Patent scape",
                 colorway = colorlist)
```

[image: insert image description here]

Comment: Please share the output of `dput(df)` to make this post reproducible without requiring external downloads.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As your code requires an external download I modified [this example](https://plotly.com/r/treemaps/#set-color-of-treemap-sectors).
Please check the following:

```
library(datasets)
library(plotly)
library(data.table)

DT <- data.table(labels = LETTERS,
                 values = 1:26)

unique_values_count <- length(unique(DT$values))

palette <- colorRampPalette(c("red", "gray"), alpha = TRUE)(unique_values_count)
assigned_colors <- c(palette[cut(DT$values, unique_values_count)])

fig <- plot_ly(
  data = DT,
  type = "treemap",
  labels =  ~ labels,
  parents = ~ NA,
  values =  ~ values,
  marker = list(colors = assigned_colors)
)
fig
```

[image: result]

Also check my related post [here](https://github.com/plotly/plotly.R/issues/1998).